# Ruble currency symbol missing in a string in ios 13

Tags: javascript, html, ios

After updating ios to 13 version I've received an issue - ruble currency is missing in a string where it is using. I use Unicode to show the ruble symbol (const EXAMPLE_STRING = 'sometext\u00A0\u20BD';) and I can't use HTML or CSS code, because I have a constant string which insert in different places. So, in devtools everything is ok, but in a view - an empty square. I understand that it's a new ios, but may be someone was face with this issue? Many thanks for answering.

I tried to add a Helvetica font, because I used only a San Francisco font, but it didn't help. I also tried to insert just ₽ - had nothing as the result.

I used - font: 15px/1 SF-Regular, Helvetica-Medium, sans-serif;

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem - just change a font to Helvetica Neue and the ruble currency starts work correctly.

Comment: There is such a font "Helvetica Heue"

Comment: fixed the font name to Helvetica Neue